# How to make file lock with bash

Tags: linux, bash, pid

I have a task to rsync a dir from remote server

```
rsync -av root@s0.foo.com:/srv/data/ /srv/data/
```

To make it run regularly and avoid Script "reEnter" issue, I create a file lock "in_progress" with rsync progress's pid, which indicate whether the program is still running.

```
lock(){
    echo $1 > in_progress
}
```

Using this function to judge whether the rsync progress is still running:

```
is_running(){
   pid=$(cat in_progress)
   return ps aux | awk '{print $2}' | grep $pid
}
```

I can get the pid to pass to function `lock` with this

```
$!
```

I had to put the rsync progress background to get the pid of rsync, so I get this

```
rsync -av root@s0.foo.com:/srv/data/ /srv/data/ & 
lock $!
```

but when rsync progress is done, I should rm the lock file
I tried this

```
rsync -av root@s0.foo.com:/srv/data/ /srv/data/ && rmLock & 
lock $!
```

... then it seems the pid I got is not the pid of rsync progress :-(

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to prevent a script from running simultaneously?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/169964/how-to-prevent-a-script-from-running-simultaneously)

Comment: It is good to indicate that your issue is solved by accepting an answer that was useful.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to prevent simultaneous executions , flock is a nice tool:

```
$ flock -n /path/to/lock/file -c "rsync -av root@s0.foo.com:/srv/data/ /srv/data/" &
```

Comment: `-n, --nb, --nonblock: Fail rather than wait if the lock cannot be immediately acquired.`

Comment: `brew install discoteq/discoteq/flock` for macOS.

Answer (score 0):

```
( rsync -av root@s0.foo.com:/srv/data/ /srv/data/ && rmLock ) &
```

Also

```
[ -d /proc/$pid ] && …
```

Comment: `( rsync -av root@s0.foo.com:/srv/data/ /srv/data/ && rmLock ) & `seems cant get the pid of rsync, but the bash pid start the command

Answer (score -1):

I just find a way to solve this, using `wait`

```
rsync -av root@s0.foo.com:/srv/data/ /srv/data/ &
pid=$!
lock $pid
wait $pid
rmLock $pid
```

thanks to tijagi, I found a more elegant way to judge whether a progress is running.