# command in terminal and in script produce different results

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and I try to grep the PID of some process. Here is what I've done in terminal:

```
# ps aux | grep xorg | grep -v 'grep' | awk '{print $2}'
```

After executing the command above, I get the result:

```
2367
```

However, then I create a script named t.sh as below:

```
#!/bin/bash
a=$(ps aux | grep $1 | grep -v 'grep' | awk '{print $2}')
echo $a
```

I execute it: `./t.sh xorg`
But I get: `2367 57270 57271`

I have no idea where the two numbers come from. I only know that the two numbers always change when I execute `./t.sh xorg` and they are adjacent (n and n + 1).

I just found another thing:
If I fix `xorg` into the script, instead of passing parameter, the two numbers will disappear.

```
#!/bin/bash
a=$(ps aux | grep xorg | grep -v 'grep' | awk '{print $2}')
echo $a
```

This script will work as expected.

## Duplicated question

[Different results between ps aux and `ps aux` inside a script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34567154/different-results-between-ps-aux-and-ps-aux-inside-a-script)

After reading the post, I still don't know what I can do to solve my problem.

Comment: I suggest `pgrep Xorg`.

Comment: @Cyrus   it seems that it can't catch all of processes containing key word as grep does.

Comment: @Cyrus  `pgrep -f` is what I need. Thank you.

Comment: Note that I used a capitalized X.